# PHP SESSION variable get's deleted each reload

Tags: php, session, web, reload

Does anybody know what can cause the $_SESSION variable to be cleared?

The session variable is used to keep track of products in the cart.
Everything worked perfect on the development and production server.

Out of a sudden the production server looses the session variable - without any changes updated. The production server is hosted with 1&1.

I added some debug information which prints the contents of GET, POST and SESSION.
Link to the website: 
http://niehues-gmbh.de

Any cart button updates the SESSION variable
But any reload and other links delete the SESSION

I do call session_start() at the beginning of index.php which loads all other contents.

Comment: empty $_SESSION = new session. Check that the session ID is remaining constant between each request. If it's not, you've got cookie settings to fix.

Comment: where are sessions being stored? Are the tmp files remaining in the folder or being cleared?

Comment: Also check the date and time on the server. If they are way out this can cause sessions to be expired immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by keeping the HTML / PHP standard.

If I remember right then there were white spaces before a header function which made the page not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of tabs.  If someone loads product detail in another tab, the browser sees it as a reload or link, and as you said, session is cleared at these times.  It's better to store your cart in the database.